# Twilio is sending their own messages for Start/Help and Stop instead of using our API reply message

Tags: twilio

Our database shows that we are sending reply messages to Twilio for START/STOP and HELP message. But when we send a text for the above messages we are getting responses from Twilio instead of our REST API Web Service response. How do we make Twilio send our responses instead of twilio response?

This seems to be working fine during the testing phase and seems to be something new after our API went Live. How do we fix this? This is causing issues as we activate/deactivate a number based on START/STOP text and that is not happening when Twilio is sending their own message as our users have to follow some procedure after they send a STOP text. Even the HELP text is not coming to our web service and instead Twilio is sending a default Help text from their side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to contact Twilio via support and ask them to turn their opt-out processing off.

Comment: is this a known issue? How come this was not there earlier when we were in testing phase?

Comment: Twilio Evangelist here: we automatically do the 'stop filtering' for you as described here: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering but if you contact support (help@twilio.com) they can help you out.